# Profit when escaping something

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, hanaah-benefit, issurei-hanaa

Is it considered a hanaa/profit from something, when the earning arrived from *escaping* this thing?

Let's say an example: Reuven was walking in a town, and suddenly he saw a church. He then changed his itinerary and took another street. And then, he found there money. Is this money considered a 'hanaa' from the church? While all his goal was to *leave* it!

Comment: It is a reward from the prisha. שכר על הפרישה